# How to name multiple csv files when writing data.frames to csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I want to save 5 files in the same folder but I am not able to change the file name at each iteration.

```
for
i=1:5
{
a=data.frame(weibull_1=rweibull(10000,2.5,10000), weibull_2=rweibull(10000,3,5000),normal=rnorm(10000,0,0.03))
write.csv(a,file="i.csv")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use paste0 to create the title for your file. Also, your for-loop constructor is a bit off:

```
for (i in 1:5)
{
  a=data.frame(weibull_1=rweibull(10000,2.5,10000), weibull_2=rweibull(10000,3,5000),normal=rnorm(10000,0,0.03))
  write.csv(a,file=paste0(i,".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(1:5, function(i) {
   a=data.frame(weibull_1=rweibull(10000,2.5,10000), 
      weibull_2=rweibull(10000,3,5000),normal=rnorm(10000,0,0.03)) 
   write.csv(a,file=paste0(i,".csv"))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either paste or paste0 in place of filename in write.csv. 
paste0 is similar to paste with just a fixed seperator e.g

paste0(a,b) = paste(a,b,sep="")

So write.csv should be changed as either

```
Write.csv(a,file=paste0(i,".csv"));
```

Or you can use

```
write.csv(a,file=paste(i,".csv",sep=""));
```